# Why does a simple Lie algebra have zero radical?

Tags: lie-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know a simple Lie algebra $L$ has only two ideals: $\lbrace0\rbrace$ and itself.  If $\lbrace0\rbrace$ is the radical (i.e., maximal solvable ideal), we are done.  If $L$ is the radical...  where is the contradiction?

I'm sure this is really simple.

Comment: Note that the "maximal solvable ideal" does not exist in general; yet it's fine for finite-dimensional Lie algebras over fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solvable radical $rad(L)$ is an ideal of $L$. So it must be $0$ or $L$, for $L$ being simple. If $rad(L)=L$, then $L$ is simple and solvable at the same time, hence $0$. If $L\neq 0$, then consequently $rad(L)=0$.

Comment: A simple Lie algebra $L$ is perfect; that is, $L=L^2$. Hence, if it is also solvable, $L=L^{(n)}=0$.